# How to use a view in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

How to use a view inside a stored procedure in sql server? I tried something like this and it says that object cannot be found

```
CREATE VIEW myview
AS
  view code


CREATE PROCEDURE myprocedure
AS
  code using myview
```

Comment: Try adding a `go` statement after the `view` definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why don't you just `select` it?

```
create procedure myProcedure 
as
  select * from myView
```

Comment: That's the problem, the select doesn't work because it doesn't know about the view.

Comment: It does not have to. If you compile that procedure, you might get an information that the view is unknown, however the procedure will be compiled. Everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
create procedure myProcedure
 As 
  select * from myview
```

Hope this helps